# Filtering multiple items in json array with sqlite json_each

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, group-by, having

I have an sqlite table with the following schema and data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Feeds (
    id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    groups JSON    NOT NULL
                   DEFAULT ('[]') 
);

INSERT INTO Feeds(groups) VALUES ('["fav1", "fav2"]');
INSERT INTO Feeds(groups) VALUES ('["fav3", "fav4"]');
INSERT INTO Feeds(groups) VALUES ('["fav1"]');
INSERT INTO Feeds(groups) VALUES ('["fav1", "fav2", "fav5"]');
```

I want to find all the rows that have both the `fav1` group and the `fav2` group. I am able to query a single group via the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Feeds, json_each(groups) WHERE json_each.value IS "fav1"
```

But i am struggling to figure out how to query more than one group, the following doesnt seem to work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Feeds, json_each(groups) WHERE json_each.value IS "fav1" AND json_each.value IS "fav2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with aggregation:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM Feeds f, json_each(groups) t 
WHERE t.value IN ('fav1', 'fav2')
GROUP BY f.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.value) = 2;
```

You can change `COUNT(DISTINCT t.value)` to just `COUNT(*)` if there are no duplicates inside the json array.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=38b7d7a245b0fe4b49e0caa8886db232).