# Filtering on date range or matching dates within comma-separated values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to search dates separated by commas. The table:

| Column Name | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | INTEGER | Primary key |
| date | TEXT | Original date of reclamation |
| remember_dates | TEXT | Dates of recalling the reclamation (comma-separated) |

Example:

| id | date | remember_dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 2023-04-25, 2023-05-18 |
| 2 | 2023-05-10 | 2023-05-04, 2023-06-15 |
| 3 | 2023-06-20 | 2023-06-10, 2023-06-25 |
| 4 | 2023-07-05 | 2023-07-01, 2023-07-10 |

I need an SQL query that retrieves rows where either `date` falls within a specified range (e.g., between '2023-05-01' and '2023-06-30') or any date within `remember_dates` matches specified range.

Following query filters `date` column but does not consider `remember_dates`:

```py
start_date = '2023-05-01'
end_date = '2023-06-30'
query = "SELECT * FROM reclamations WHERE date(date) BETWEEN date(?) AND date(?)"
params = [start_date, end_date]
```

I also tried:

```
import sqlite3

# Connect to the SQLite database
conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Define the search dates
start_date = '2023-01-01'
end_date = '2023-12-31'

# Execute the query to retrieve rows based on the search dates
query = "SELECT * FROM reclamations WHERE date(date) BETWEEN date(?) AND date(?) OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM reclamations WHERE remember_dates LIKE ? AND CAST(strftime('%Y-%m-%d', remember_dates) AS DATE) BETWEEN date(?) AND date(?))"
params = [start_date, end_date, '%,'+start_date+',%', start_date, end_date]

cursor.execute(query, params)

# Fetch and print the matching rows
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)

# Close the cursor and the database connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

But only `date` column is working.

Comment: As far as the database is concerned that's a single string, not values. Use a separate table if you want to store multiple related values. That's the most basic table rule - one cell contains one atomic value

Comment: If the string field contained a JSON array, you could use `json_each` to expand the contents as if they were a table and filter them. This is shown [in this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71535753/filtering-multiple-items-in-json-array-with-sqlite-json-each) The downside is that the contents of that string can't be indexed, so the query will have to scan every single row in `reclamations`, parse the JSON column and check for matches.

Comment: You can't modify the items in that JSON string directly either, you need to use UPDATE with one of the JSON functions to create and store a new JSON string. That's precisely because only one value is stored per cell. You could avoid this hassle with a separate related table, eg `ReclamationDates(ID,ReclamationID,Date)`. With such a table the query becomes `SELECT ... FROM Reclamation r INNER JOIN ReclamationDates d on r.ID=d.ReclamationID where d.Date between ? AND ?`. If you use indexes on the ID and date columns, the lookup will be very fast